# Determining where program files should be stored in Java

Tags: java, path

On Mac OS X, files that a program uses for itself should be stored in `~/Library/Application /Support`. On Windows, the relevant directory is `C:\\Program Files`. Obviously, on other operating systems, the directory differs still.

Is there an environment or system variable that can be fetched in Java that will reasonably reliably return this path? If not, what is the conventional manner for determining where to store files that the program needs but that the user has no need to see?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use the Program Files map, but the Application Data map in Windows. I'd use something like this:

```
private String dir;
private String OS = (System.getProperty("os.name")).toUpperCase();

if (OS.contains("WIN")) //if its windows, get the APPDATA map
{
    dir= System.getenv("AppData");
}
else //else it's Linux or Mac
{
    dir= System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support";
}
```

You'll want to first determine it's Windows. If it is, get the APPDATA map. If it's not, get the Application Support map.
Also, if you want to hide the folder for users, start the name of your folder with a dot (.) That way, the folder will be hidden most of the times.

I hope this helps!